# Facebook web application extended permissions second step dont show

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-c#-sdk

**Update2**
This post is getting old but still relevant.. Below is whe way I solved it. I marked the other guys answer because I think it answers the question better. I'm calling a similar method(I'am about to refactor:)) in accountcontroller. The string should be a list... I think you get it.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Use this method when an action fails due to lack of priviligies. It will redirect user to facebook with provided permission request.
    /// Refactor to handle list of request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="permission"></param>
    private static void AddAdditionalPermissions(string permission)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(permission + " not authorized for user.");
        string facebook_urlAuthorize_base = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize";
        string scope = permission; //see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ for extended permissions
        string urlAuthorize = facebook_urlAuthorize_base;
        urlAuthorize += "?client_id=" + AppId;
        urlAuthorize += "&redirect_uri=" + "https://fbd.anteckna.nu/";
        urlAuthorize += "&scope=" + scope;

        //redirect the users browser to Facebook to ask the user to authorize our Facebook application
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(urlAuthorize, true); //this cannot be done using WebRequest since facebook may need to show dialogs in the users browser
    }
```

Then every method making a call to facebook like /me/home with facebok C# SDK catches FacebookOAuthException and redirects to the folling method. This is how we apply the best practise of not asking permissions from users up front but when needed. This method should have  aredirect url that matches as well but we've just get going :)

Hope it helps!

```
/// <summary>
    /// Check for what permissions to request or different ways to handle FacebookOAuthExceptions.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="foae">The exception object</param>
    public static void HandleAuthorizationsExceptions(FacebookOAuthException foae)
    {
        if (foae.Message.Contains("publish_permissions"))
        {
            AddAdditionalPermissions("publish_permissions");
        }
        else if (foae.Message.Contains("read_stream"))
        {
            AddAdditionalPermissions("read_stream");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Unhandled error at:" + foae.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

**Update**: This behaviour is caused by .Net oauth implementation which has the scope hard coded in a sealed class. Added figure 4 to show the request parameter where the lack of additional scopes besides "email"(which is sent with all requests by .net oauth provider). Adding ",publish_stream" to the query string gives me the wanted behaviour. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Please do not submit answers or comments about facebook best practices or alternative solutions. I have an alternative solution but would like this to work with default registerfacebookclient parameters. I have updated the application to oly use publish_stream according to the two answers specifying on what permissions I'm asking for.

figure 4[image: Image showing scope parameter in query string]

**Original question:**
I'm setting up an application (C#.Net4.5 MVC4, razor views) which need pretty much all available user permissions from facebook.
You can see code examples below how I have set it all up.

The problem is that when clicking "okay" in figure 1, Facebook sends me back to my application. As I understand there should be an additional screen(figure2) asking for the "heavier" permissions. As of now I only get the permissions stated in figure one. That part works...

Figure 1
[image: Facebook permissions dialog C#]

Figure 2
[image]

So, using basic
AuthConfig.cs

```
var facebooksocialData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            facebooksocialData.Add("scope", "email,publish_stream,read_stream,publish_actions,manage_pages,create_event,offline_access");
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
                appId: "165359673639901",
                appSecret: "15091cb2094a1996ae6c7b324f0300e6",
                displayName: "Facebook",
                extraData: facebooksocialData);
```

This is how I handle the response but here facebook has not prompted the user for the extended permissions but only for email,

AccountController.cs

```
 //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            // Save the accesstoken into session
            Session["accesstoken"] = result.ExtraData["accesstoken"];
            Session["id"] = result.ExtraData["id"];

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
            }
        }
```

The closest to an answer I could find was a wp plugin which had the same issue. Their problem was solved by setting domain to localhost. This is how my application is set up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same problem. As you did, I configured the RegisterFacebookClient with dictionary to define my app's scope, and unfortunately the request didn't include the scope as I configured. So I found [that](http://mvc4beginner.com/Sample-Code/Facebook-Twitter/MVC-4-oAuth-Facebook-Login-EMail-Problem-Solved.html). It seems that would work, but it wasn't enough. So I found [this](http://savvydev.com/authenticating-facebook-users-with-mvc-4-oauth-and-obtaining-scope-permissions/).

So here is what solve my problems:

First of all I added this new client to my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyApp.UI.Infrastructure
{
    public class FacebookScopedClient : IAuthenticationClient
    {
        private string appId;
        private string appSecret;
        private string scope;

        private const string baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=";
        public const string graphApiToken = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?";
        public const string graphApiMe = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?";

        private static string GetHTML(string URL)
        {
            string connectionString = URL;

            try
            {
                System.Net.HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionString);
                myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                //// Get the response
                WebResponse webResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                ////
                StreamReader ioStream = new StreamReader(respStream);
                string pageContent = ioStream.ReadToEnd();
                //// Close streams
                ioStream.Close();
                respStream.Close();
                return pageContent;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }

        private IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessCode, string redirectURI)
        {
            string token = GetHTML(graphApiToken + "client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectURI) + "&client_secret=" + appSecret + "&code=" + accessCode);
            if (token == null || token == "")
            {
                return null;
            }
            string access_token = token.Substring(token.IndexOf("access_token="), token.IndexOf("&"));
            string data = GetHTML(graphApiMe + "fields=id,name,email,username,gender,link&" + access_token);

            // this dictionary must contains
            Dictionary<string, string> userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
            return userData;
        }

        public FacebookScopedClient(string appId, string appSecret, string scope)
        {
            this.appId = appId;
            this.appSecret = appSecret;
            this.scope = scope;
        }

        public string ProviderName
        {
            get { return "facebook"; }
        }

        public void RequestAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
        {
            string url = baseUrl + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()) + "&scope=" + scope;
            context.Response.Redirect(url);
        }

        public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context)
        {
            string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];

            string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.OriginalString;
            //From this we need to remove code portion
            rawUrl = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "&code=[^&]*", "");

            IDictionary<string, string> userData = GetUserData(code, rawUrl);

            if (userData == null)
                return new AuthenticationResult(false, ProviderName, null, null, null);

            string id = userData["id"];
            string username = userData["username"];
            userData.Remove("id");
            userData.Remove("username");

            AuthenticationResult result = new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, id, username, userData);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I put it on a folder "infrastructure" in my asp.net solution with oder stuff, next I change my old configuration, in order to use the new facebook client, as follows:

Old code:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
appId: "<app-id>",
appSecret: "<app-secret>",
displayName: "Facebook",
extraData: facebookExtraData);
```

New Code:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(
                    new FacebookScopedClient(
                        "<app-id>",
                        "<app-secret>",
                        "scope"), 
                    "Facebook", 
                    null);
```

That's it. It may help you, as helped me.

Comment: This is strange. Your solutions works for me, but only local. Once I publish my website to the cloud, the facebook authentication no longer works. My app domains are correctly configured on facebook, because the default facebookclient works.

Comment: @Bastaspast, the problem in azure is that the role instace URL is call within its specific network port, as the property 'context.Request.Url.OriginalString' return it. So it miss match the URL passed to the facebook. I haven't found an elegant way to solve it, but I did this:
 `#if !DEBUG
            rawUrl = rawUrl.Replace(":" + context.Request.Url.Port, "");
#endif`
Therefor everything will work smoothly localy and on the cloud. But this solution only alow you to run in DEBUG in localy, in oder hand you can comment that line with in this cases.

Answer (score 1):

Is your app registered for these scopes? I'm familiar with Google OAuth, they have a separate scope that maps to one permission. Your app should be registered for the scopes, in order to get the 2nd window. Else, you'll have access only to the public info that your 1st popup asks for..

Comment: I hadn't registered the app with the scopes. However, that did not solve my problem. Investigating my problem further I saw this behaviour is because the extradata that is provided as scope only sets email when the request is made. The problem is somewhere in the use of .Net OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `offline_access` does not exist any more, so it from the permissions you are asking for.

> *"[app] which need pretty much all available user permissions from facebook"*

Facebook actively discourages asking for heaps of permissions straight from the beginning "just in case" because they might be needed later. One should only ask for an extended permission when it is actually needed for an action the user just triggered for the first time.

Also, you are supposed to ask for "read" and "write" permissions separately.

I don't know if these aspects are actually triggering your error - but I know that Facebook has already been sending out developer alerts for the read/write thing; although an FB employee confirmed that those alerts can be ignored *for now*, they might start *enforcing* this at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your advice CBroe. I'm building an application with an interface for the blind and deaf community. This requires me to use as few interactions and popups as possible.

Comment: I think OP is correct and his scopes are being lost somewhere in the SDK, not in the actual call to Facebook

Comment: Magnus Karlsson I am also facing the same issue, did you get any solution of yours?

Comment: @IsaiyavanBabuKaran Yes, I made a method to send requests to facebook which I'm able to use at every FacebookOAuthException. WOrks like a charm. I'll update with som code tomorrow. By the way, I think Matheus code looks great when you need permissions up front! I'm upvoting it right now :)