# Error validating verification code issue with ASP.Net MVC 4 auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC4 application to allow application to post some data on user's wall on their behalf. I am using inbuilt oAuth support that comes with MVC4. As I read that default oAuth library does not provide feature to add scope, thus to solve this issue I followed [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717002/facebook-web-application-extended-permissions-second-step-dont-show)

But further I am facing an obstacle where facebook graph api throws this exception:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

When I searched about this issue, I found [this solution](http://thefacebookdev.com/2013/01/fixing-facebook-error-verification-code/)
But even placing "/" at the end doesn't solve the issue and I keep getting same error. 
I have follwing oAuth dialog url:

> `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=431734730282664&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A1724%252FAccount%252FExternalLoginCallback%253F__provider__%253Dfacebook%2526__sid__%253D038708985bbe463e89cfb8914a19d810%26scope%3Dpublish_stream%26client_id%3D4317347****82664%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1724%2FAccount%2FExternalLoginCallback%3F__provider__%3Dfacebook%26__sid__%3D038708985bbe463e89cfb8914a19d810%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page`

and following returning url from graph api

> `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=431734730282664&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1724/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=facebook&amp;__sid__=038708985bbe463e89cfb8914a19d810&client_secret=1fd7c90f*******6d9cc58e85e01a&code=AQBBS8U3xi31n8yh0dtJaOtG9YEuLKP**********mk_SPrEDwh7rJbGPuyOehI7Buo4wSMK8******igIl4VaRW5mQ5cE3YnXn4adkmP7tD0_JRT-SRDa_5PyKfknfQ5sRK7t6d0Ng4pccPSyeDJoUiZ7jWKfY-Sq-2LlaXkiJW5cYWiPtjAeXLPGvcSnMw91edwe41S-qdg9Lu5XTijEN3mMC8onPv86t802NhDs0sTFscWoGjxQEE9kioK5-0BnR384qrI7DGNf_oAIb88L83Z_mITvnv_dkq265lZztmkkOt0`

I don't find a difference between the redirect uri as documentation says that **redirect uri in both the urls must be same**. 
Could anyone please suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder that I've encountered the same problem, but it's caused for different reasons.
The shown return paths are different, but they need to be exactly the same, as follows.

The firt one corespond to:

> `http://localhost:1724/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__=facebook&__sid__=038708985bbe463e89cfb8914a19d810`

In the other hand, the second one is:

> `http://localhost:1724/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?__provider__`

The values were decoded using an [js decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) and later on the chrome network debugger inspected.

If you pay attention in second your url, you may notice that the url path isn't correctly encoded.

The characters '/', ':', '&', ';' and '=' from the first url can't be read, while the second one it's clearyly readble.

To solve the problem you may need to encoded it.

Maybe be usefull the [HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx) to do it.