# How to access the users Email id with asp.net mvc facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api

I am using this [Link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc) as a starting point as i am new to Asp.net MVC as such.

I have been able to get the data of the facebook users **what permissions should i use to get the users Email ID and where?**

```
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
if (response.ContainsKey("verified"))
{
    facebookVerified = response["verified"];
}
else
{
    facebookVerified = false;
}
db.ExternalUsers.Add(new ExternalUserInformation
{
     UserId = newUser.UserId,
     FullName = me.name,
     Link = me.link,
     Email = model.Email, // Want the Email ID from Facebook
     Gender = me.gender,
     Verified = facebookVerified
});
```

LOGIN CODE:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13125765/1346943

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, pls write the correct answer and accept it

Comment: No it hasn't been resolved yet

Comment: Pls show the login code you've used.

Comment: Have solved the problem

Comment: Cool. You can share your answer here and accept it and also give bounty, else the bounty will be wasted ! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are missing here is getting additional permission for getting the email address from facebook.

See the below two screenshot, second screenshot requests for additional information including email.

#### Basic Permission

[image]

#### More Permissions

[image]

To do that you need to this additional required info as "scope".

I did a little tutorial on how to login with facebook today and can be read here - [Using Facebook Login with ASP.NET MVC 4](http://yassershaikh.com/using-facebook-login-with-asp-net-mvc-4/). This will answer most of your queries.

For your question here is what you should do:

Create a **FacebookScopedClient** class (code below) and then in your **AuthConfig.cs** use it like this

```
var facebooksocialData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
facebooksocialData.Add("scope", "email, publish_stream, read_stream");

OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new FacebookScopedClient(
    appId: "xxxxxxxx",
    appSecret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    scope:"email, user_likes, friends_likes, user_birthday),
    "Facebook",
    null
);
```

Code for FacebookScopedClient class -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class FacebookScopedClient : IAuthenticationClient
{
    private string appId;
    private string appSecret;
    private string scope;

    private const string baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=";
    public const string graphApiToken = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?";
    public const string graphApiMe = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?";

    private static string GetHTML(string URL)
    {
        string connectionString = URL;

        try
        {
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(connectionString);
            myRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //// Get the response
            WebResponse webResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            ////
            StreamReader ioStream = new StreamReader(respStream);
            string pageContent = ioStream.ReadToEnd();
            //// Close streams
            ioStream.Close();
            respStream.Close();
            return pageContent;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }

    private IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessCode, string redirectURI)
    {
        string token = GetHTML(graphApiToken + "client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectURI) + "&client_secret=" + appSecret + "&code=" + accessCode);
        if (token == null || token == "")
        {
            return null;
        }
        string access_token = token.Substring(token.IndexOf("access_token="), token.IndexOf("&"));
        string data = GetHTML(graphApiMe + "fields=id,name,email,username,gender,link&" + access_token);

        // this dictionary must contains
        Dictionary<string, string> userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);
        return userData;
    }

    public FacebookScopedClient(string appId, string appSecret, string scope)
    {
        this.appId = appId;
        this.appSecret = appSecret;
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public string ProviderName
    {
        get { return "Facebook"; }
    }

    public void RequestAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, Uri returnUrl)
    {
        string url = baseUrl + appId + "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl.ToString()) + "&scope=" + scope;
        context.Response.Redirect(url);
    }

    public AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthentication(System.Web.HttpContextBase context)
    {
        string code = context.Request.QueryString["code"];

        string rawUrl = context.Request.Url.OriginalString;
        //From this we need to remove code portion
        rawUrl = Regex.Replace(rawUrl, "&code=[^&]*", "");

        IDictionary<string, string> userData = GetUserData(code, rawUrl);

        if (userData == null)
            return new AuthenticationResult(false, ProviderName, null, null, null);

        string id = userData["id"];
        string username = userData["username"];
        userData.Remove("id");
        userData.Remove("username");

        AuthenticationResult result = new AuthenticationResult(true, ProviderName, id, username, userData);
        return result;
    }
}
```

References:

- [Facebook web application extended permissions second step dont show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717002/facebook-web-application-extended-permissions--) second-step-dont-show/18904735#18904735
- [Authenticating Facebook users with MVC 4 OAuth AND obtaining Scope Permissions!](http://savvydev.com/authenticating-facebook-users-with-mvc-4-oauth-and-obtaining-scope-permissions/)

Comment: Just for reference, issues i faced. Firstly there is a type missing " before ) in this line "scope:"email, user_likes, friends_likes, user_birthday),". Now most importantly, **username is deprecated in newer facebook api and this will cause exceptions as no data will be returned. So remove username from this line string data = GetHTML(graphApiMe + "fields=id,name,email,username,gender,link&" + access_token); and also as we are not recieving it so i changed string username = userData["username"]; to string username = userData["name"]; and removed this line: userData.Remove("username");** Cheers